# How to correctly capture selected text into a variable in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create my first Chrome extension - a duplicate of the right-click google search option.

This is what I have so far

```
function searchGoogle() {
  var selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
  var serviceCall = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=' + selectedText;
  chrome.tabs.create({url: serviceCall});
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "title": "mySearch",
  "contexts":["selection"],
  "onclick": searchGoogle
});
```

The problem is that the selected text is not being captured, and the query that executes on any selected text is `http://www.google.com/search?q=`.

What am I doing wrong here? Why does `window.getSelection().toString()` not work?

---

After what Bryan suggested, I tried this

```
var query;
function getText(ocd) {
   query = ocd.selectionText;
}

function searchGoogle() {
  var serviceCall = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=' + query;
  chrome.tabs.create({url: serviceCall});
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "title": "mySearch",
  "contexts":["selection"],
  "onclick": searchGoogle
});
```

but it searches for `http://www.google.com/search?q=undefined`

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Google's reference on the OnClickData](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contextMenus.html#type-OnClickData) object. When you click on your context menu item, it will send one of those as the first argument to the specified function. So, first of all, you probably want to add a variable to hold it. Once you have that variable (here `ocd`) you can access the properties listed by Google with `ocd.*`. In this case, we want `ocd.selectionText`.

Most likely, you'll need to make the following change:

```
// Handle click event and store OnClickData object in first argument
function searchGoogle(ocd) {
  var serviceCall = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=' + ocd.selectionText;
  chrome.tabs.create({url: serviceCall});
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "title": "mySearch %s", // display "MySearch [selected text]" in menu
  "contexts":["selection"],
  "onclick": searchGoogle // pass an OnClickData object to searchGoogle on click
});
```

Since you're just starting out, I'll heavily recommend looking to [Google's Developer's Guide](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/devguide.html). It usually has what you need in terms of which methods are available, what values they return, etc. for all of their custom `chrome.*` APIs.

Also, `window.getSelection().getString()` is being called from your background script, right? It actually *does* work, but it works by returning whatever text you've *selected on your background page*. Since you usually can't interact with your extension's background page, that's probably a blank string.

Comment: I tried using ocd.selectionText, but it captures `undefined`. Please see my updated question for details.

Comment: You don't need `var query` or `getText`, you just needed to change `searchGoogle` to have an argument to capture the click data from the context menu click. You get undefined because you never define `query`. You initialize `query`, but then when the user clicks on your menu item, he goes straight to `searchGoogle` (without an argument to capture the OnClickData object).

I'm adding the full code that you should use to my response. Hopefully that clears things up a bit.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to use an extra variable because I wanted to display the selected text in the title - "mySearch " + query.

Comment: @Lazer For that you just need to change `"title"` from `"mySearch"` to `"mySearch %s"` and keep the rest of my code as is. I'm updating the snippet above.